# Retrieving video file information in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, video, directshow.net

I have a admin panel where i am uploading some video and settings some of its parameters manually to save it in database fields, like FileName, FileSize in Mb and Video duration.Now the requirement changed and it became something this, immediately after selecting a video file (either of them avi, mpeg, mp4, mpg, dat or vob etc), in a file upload control, the properties of the video file will get immediately set to its corresponding label or textbox.

I have tried a lot but unable to find any event related to the same. Also one more issue i faced while getting the duration of the video. I have tried DirectShow and FfMpeg but of no use. So basically i am  stucked with the problems where I need your help. I am only able to get the file name immediately in javascript. So i need your suggestions.

How To retrieve the duration of video,immediately after video selection in fileupload control either in javascript or c# (any open source managed lib will b heartily welcome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a client app to upload, that can collect the information you want from user's machine.

Another approach is to upload to the server, process the information you need to and then send it back to browser, but that may take a while and it won't be instant like after selection.

For a lib to work with video, haven't used any, but you can try [VLC.NET](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx) in C#, for javascript i think it will be hard to find if there is any.